# Objects created in another activity are not visible in Main activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

I have two basic classes in my code: Airport and Flight (Departure and Arrival). Airport consists of a list of arrival flight objects and a list of departure flight objects.
In my Main activity i hold a list of airport objects and represent them in a List View. With a touch on a list view object I launch a new activity for showing all the arrival flights of that airport object (ActivityArrivalFlights), in which i hold the airport object as a field. In this activity, there's a functionality for adding arrival flights to the same object. I represent the flights also in a List View and add flights via Array Adapter.

The problem is this: When a flight object is created and added to the airport, it is there as long as the activity is alive. When ActivityArrivalFlights gets destroyed and the focus is on the main activity, the previously added flight objects are not in that airport.

Here's the code for the two activities. Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int FILL_AIRPORT_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int EDIT_AIRPORT_REQUEST = 2;

    static final String EDIT_AIRPORT_OBJECT_KEY = "editable";
    static final String EDIT_AIRPORT_POSITION_KEY = "position";
    static final String SELECTED_AIRPORT_KEY = "selectedAirport";
    static final String ALL_FLIGHTS_LIST_KEY = "allFlights";

    private static final String AIRPORTS_STATE = "airportsState";

    private Button btnAddAirport;
    private ListView lvAirports;

    private ArrayList<Airport> airports;
    private ArrayAdapter<Airport> airportArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAddAirport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddAirport);
        lvAirports = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lwAirports);
        btnAddAirport.setOnClickListener(this::onButtonAddAirportClick);
        lvAirports.setOnItemClickListener(this::onListViewItemClicked);


        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            airports = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(AIRPORTS_STATE);
        else
            airports = new ArrayList<>();

        airportArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, airports);
        lvAirports.setAdapter(airportArrayAdapter);
        lvAirports.invalidateViews();
        registerForContextMenu(lvAirports);
        if(savedInstanceState == null)
            addCodeForTesting();
    }

    private void addCodeForTesting() {
         /* TEMPORARY CODE FOR TESTING*/
        Airport munich = new Airport("MunichAirport", "Munich", "MU", 1234);
        Airport skopje = new Airport("Aleksandar Veliki", "Skopje", "SK", 4321);
        skopje.addArrivalFlight(munich, new Date(), new Date());
        airportArrayAdapter.add(skopje);
        airportArrayAdapter.add(munich);
    }

    private void onButtonAddAirportClick(View view){
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ActivityAddAirport.class), FILL_AIRPORT_REQUEST);
    }

    private void onListViewItemClicked(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id){
        Airport airport = airports.get(position);
        showFlightsActivity(airport);
    }

    private void showFlightsActivity(Airport airport) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityArrivalFlights.class);
        ArrayList<Airport> filteredList = filterAirports(airports, airport);
        intent.putExtra(SELECTED_AIRPORT_KEY, airport);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ALL_FLIGHTS_LIST_KEY, filteredList);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private static ArrayList<Airport> filterAirports(List<Airport> original, Airport except){
        ArrayList<Airport> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Airport airport : original) {
            if(!airport.equals(except))
                filtered.add(airport);
        }
        return filtered;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == FILL_AIRPORT_REQUEST){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Airport airport = data.getParcelableExtra(ActivityAddAirport.AIRPORT_OBJECT_KEY);
                airportArrayAdapter.add(airport);
            }
        }
        else if(requestCode == EDIT_AIRPORT_REQUEST){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Airport editedAirport = data.getParcelableExtra(ActivityAddAirport.AIRPORT_OBJECT_KEY);
                int airportPosition = data.getIntExtra(ActivityAddAirport.AIRPORT_POSITION, 0);
                airports.remove(airportPosition);
                airports.add(airportPosition, editedAirport);
                airportArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                lvAirports.invalidateViews();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Airport changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(AIRPORTS_STATE, airports);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu_context_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.context_edit) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            editListViewItem(info.position);
            return true;
        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.context_delete){
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            deleteListViewItem(info.position);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void editListViewItem(int position) {
        Intent editIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityAddAirport.class);
        Airport changingAirport = (Airport) lvAirports.getItemAtPosition(position);
        editIntent.putExtra(EDIT_AIRPORT_OBJECT_KEY, changingAirport);
        editIntent.putExtra(EDIT_AIRPORT_POSITION_KEY, position);
        startActivityForResult(editIntent, EDIT_AIRPORT_REQUEST);
    }

    private void deleteListViewItem(int position){
        airportArrayAdapter.remove(airports.get(position));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ActivityArrivalFlights extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int FILL_ARRIVAL_FLIGHT_REQUEST = 1;

    static final String AIRPORT_THIS_KEY = "thisAirport";
    static final String ALL_AIRPORTS_EXCEPT_THIS_KEY = "allExceptThis";

    private Airport airport;
    private ArrayList<Airport> allAirportsExceptThis;

    private ArrayAdapter<ArrivalFlight> lvArrivalsAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_arrival_flights);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarAF);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fabAddArrival = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAddArrival);
        fabAddArrival.setOnClickListener(this::onFabAddArrivalClick);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        airport = intent.getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.SELECTED_AIRPORT_KEY);
        allAirportsExceptThis = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(MainActivity.ALL_FLIGHTS_LIST_KEY);

        setUpListView();
    }

    private void setUpListView(){
        ListView lvArrivals = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvArrivals);
        lvArrivalsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, airport.getArrivals());
        lvArrivals.setAdapter(lvArrivalsAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_choose_flights, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem arrivals = menu.findItem(R.id.arrivals);
        MenuItem departures = menu.findItem(R.id.departures);
        if (arrivals.isEnabled())
            arrivals.setEnabled(false);
        if (!departures.isEnabled())
            departures.setEnabled(true);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.departures){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityDepartureFlights.class);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SELECTED_AIRPORT_KEY, airport);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void onFabAddArrivalClick(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityAddArrivalFlight.class);
        intent.putExtra(AIRPORT_THIS_KEY, airport);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ALL_AIRPORTS_EXCEPT_THIS_KEY, allAirportsExceptThis);
        startActivityForResult(intent, FILL_ARRIVAL_FLIGHT_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == FILL_ARRIVAL_FLIGHT_REQUEST){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
               ArrivalFlight flight = data.getParcelableExtra(ActivityAddArrivalFlight.FILLED_FLIGHT_ENTRY);
               lvArrivalsAdapter.add(flight);
               Toast.makeText(this, "Flight added!\n" + airport.getArrivals().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see No reason why upon ActivityArrivalFlights's destruction the MainActivity will be updated with new flights.

You are not returning any result to MainActivity (from ActivityArrivalFlights)
In order to return data to MainActivity, in your case returning the flight which have been added you need to do something like:

In MainActivity:

```
final int NEW_FLIGHT_RESULT = 5; // Just an identifier number / what ever you want;

// Start ActivityArrivalFlights for result (which you are not doing):

private void showFlightsActivity(Airport airport) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityArrivalFlights.class);
    ArrayList<Airport> filteredList = filterAirports(airports, airport);
    intent.putExtra(SELECTED_AIRPORT_KEY, airport);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ALL_FLIGHTS_LIST_KEY, filteredList);
    startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_FLIGHT_RESULT);  // Here start for result
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == NEW_FLIGHT_RESULT){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Flight f = data.getParcelableExtra("NEW_FILGHT_DATA");
            // Here add the new flight to the airport object you are maintaining !!!
        }
     }
```

From ActivityArrivalFlights:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // You can wrap this with: If(newFlightsAdded()) { ... }:
    Intent output = new Intent();
    output.putExtra("NEW_FILGHT_DATA", newFlight);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, output);
    finish();
}
```

That is the whole concept i guess you missed, My code is quick and dirty so clean it up and use as you wish.

**NOTE !!! :** Passing objects between activities using intents (intent.putExtra(...) will pass a copy of an object and not the same object).

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I was looking for. I know this concept. 

The idea is, I pass a reference of the airport object to the ActivityArrivalFlights activity. Any changes made to the same object should be visible anywhere, because its the same object, I just pass it's reference around. What has made me think is why are these changes not visible in the main activity.

Comment: @DraganApostolski intent.putExtra passes a copy of the object and not the object itself, meaning changing something on the object received by intent.getExtra of any kind will change the object copy. you can check if the object is infact a copy by making the airporst static (for test only) and compare the object passed in putExtra to the original static one (which is defined in the MainActivity), compare refs like:  airports == intentAirports . So the good practice would be to return back the new flight as a result as I mentioned above.

Comment: I really did not read the documentation on this method, I really thought that intent.putExtra passes a reference. Thank you, now knowing this I will find a solution.